# Sections without numbers

Tags: sectioning, table-of-contents

Does anybody know how to eliminate the numbering only in sections D and E, whereby the title itself for the Section D or Section E should start exactly at the beginning of the line? Additionally, the section numbers should not appear within the table of contents and should start exactly at the beginning of the corresponding line. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\section {Section A}
\section {Section B}
\section {Section C}
\section {Section D}
\section {Section E}
\end{document}
```

Comment: do you mean `\section*{Section D}`?

Comment: @cmhughes exactly, I've tried it, and the chronological number disappears, that's what i wanted to have, but after doing so, both sections are not shown within the table of contents any more, any idea?

Answer (score 17):

You can also use `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}` to get rid of numbers:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section A}
\section{Section B}
\section{Section C}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} %% no numbering
\section{Section D}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} %% Start numbering again
\section{Section E}

\end{document}
```